# Why do I need to import "VToolbarItems"?

Tags: vuetify.js

I see examples of using Vuetify in which only the template is show and there is no importing of Vuetify components like VTool, much less VToolTitle, VToolItems, etc. But if I don't import and declare them I get "Unknown custom element: ..."

I did not load vuetify with "vue add vuetify". Is that necessary? Is there something missing that I can add, if so?

In my main.js I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

This App.vue works:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="vuetify-app">
    <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        Pro
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
         <v-btn flat>List</v-btn>
         <v-btn flat>Profile</v-btn>
         <v-btn flat>Help</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
    <SignUp  msg="Welcome"/>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {VApp, VToolbar, VToolbarTitle, VToolbarItems, VSpacer, VBtn} from 'vuetify/lib'
import SignUp from './components/SignUp.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    VApp,
    VToolbar,
    VToolbarTitle,
    VToolbarItems,
    VSpacer,
    VBtn,
    SignUp
  }
}
</script>
```

But if I comment out:

```
import {VApp, VToolbar, VToolbarTitle, VToolbarItems, VSpacer, VBtn} from 'vuetify/lib'
```

and all the "VApp, VToolbarTitle, etc" I get the Unknown custom element message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
```

is how you import components [a la carte](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/a-la-carte).

If you instead want all of the components to be registered globally, import and install Vuetify like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify' // omit /lib

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```